# Laravel Route group issue

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have been using laravel for a while now, but I stumbled across an error which I have never encountered before. It is probably me overlooking it, but with the route file given below, the route group with the prefix account gives a blank page. When going to `/account/anunregisteredroute` it does give a `httpnotfoundexception`

My routes.php file:
http://pastebin.com/EnnGSm10

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `/` before the parameter you can solve this issue:

```
Route::get('/{username}', ['as' => 'account-profile', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getProfile']);
```

This piece of code worked for me:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'account'], function () {
    Route::get('/{username}', ['as' => 'account-profile', 'uses' => function($username){
        echo $username;
    }]);
    Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'account-edit-profile', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getUpdate', 'before' => 'auth']);
    Route::post('profile', ['as' => 'account-edit-profile', 'uses' => 'AccountController@postUpdate', 'before' => 'auth|csrf']);

    Route::group(['before' => 'guest'], function () {
        Route::get('create', ['as' => 'account-create', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getCreate']);
        Route::get('signin', ['as' => 'account-signin', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getSignin']);

        Route::group(['before' => 'csrf'], function() {
            Route::post('create', ['as' => 'account-create', 'uses' => 'AccountController@postCreate']);
            Route::post('signin', ['as' => 'account-signin', 'uses' => 'AccountController@postSignin']);
        });
    });
});
```

I got the expected output.

Comment: that didn't work, however the issue is with that route. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does the error message provide more information?